# when i connect django API to my app in android studio it shows error

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio, django-rest-framework

I have a Django version that is installed on my laptop and I would like to connect the API to my android app.

I have created a virtual environment too.

I am not able to connect to my Django API, so please help me with how to connect to API. Thanks in advance.

I surfed on the internet but I couldn't get any output.I am posting questions herein for the first time sorry for any mistakes done.

I want to connect the Django API to my project.i want the information to be seen in json form in mobile app.

[image: Image file]

when I connect my Django API app made in android studio, It shows an error, I have attached a file above.

I am attaching my android file.

I have used a retrofit library. And I want to connect the API to my app.

MainActivity.java

```
ListView listView;
GridView gridView;
public String cap;
public String cap1;
String[] pid;
String[] ptitle;
String[] pdes;
String[] dt;
String[] lk;
TextView name,descrip;

int capnum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(djangoApi.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    djangoApi api = retrofit.create(djangoApi.class);
    name= findViewById(R.id.text);
    descrip=findViewById(R.id.image);
    Call<List<PostTable>> call = api.gettabledata();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<PostTable>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<PostTable>> call, Response<List<PostTable>> response) {
            List<PostTable> pt = response.body();
            assert pt != null;
            String[] pid = new String[pt.size()];
            String[] ptitle = new String[pt.size()];
            String[] pdes = new String[pt.size()];
            String[] pdt = new String[pt.size()];
            String[] plk = new String[pt.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < pt.size(); i++) {
                pid[i] = pt.get(i).getid();
                ptitle[i] = pt.get(i).gettitle();
                pdes[i] = pt.get(i).getdescription();
                pdt[i] = pt.get(i).getdatetime();
                plk[i] = pt.get(i).getlikes();

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < pt.size(); i++) {
                if (ptitle[i].equalsIgnoreCase("drhsrh")) {
                    capnum = i;
                    cap = pdes[capnum];
                    cap1=ptitle[capnum];

                }
            }
            name.setText(cap1);
            descrip.setText(cap);
            //Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(cap).into(imageView);
            //name.setText(cap1);
}
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<PostTable>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

this is the code for Interface class

```
interface djangoApi {
    String BASE_URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/";
    @GET("post_table/?format=json")
    Call<List<PostTable>> gettabledata();
```

Comment: Can you clear your answer

Comment: How you're making call from app to server ? Kindly make sure that address is accessible before "assuming" their is some issue in app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Please check this documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

If you want to test in local, please add this android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the application tag, of the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```